# How to use react hook useeffect with adding event-handler depended on state?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, addeventlistener, react-hooks, use-effect

I have an authorize component, included another components - fields like username, pass etc. I try to create react hook useeffect, where I want to add a subscribe on "X" keyDown event. On this event I want to execute Authorize() function, which is located in component body (not hook body), and depends on authorize component state.

So, the only solution, that I found was:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
      event.key === 'X' && defineIsAuthorizationAvailable() && authorize()
    }
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
  })
```

But I dont think its correct, because this subscribing/unsubscribing executes on every change of user state. Please, help.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to run a certain functions in `useEffect` contingent upon a boolean state value, right?
If so, you can use conditionals within `useEffect` hooks and re-render when some state changes. 
For example, something like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
if(authorizeBoolean) {
const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
      event.key === 'X' && defineIsAuthorizationAvailable() && authorize()
    }
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
}

}, [authorizeBoolean]);
```

Comment: good answer. it's just that `authorizeBoolean` should not restrict adding a listener. Rather, should only limit `authorize()`.

Comment: If you mean that I need to toggle authorizeBoolean only one time after component mount, as I understand, state item user will have a value = initialValue when Authorize() executes, that is not correct.